# How to include javascript third party library in ionic app?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, bower, path-finding

I am sorry to ask this silly question. I am trying to use pathfinding.js (https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js/) in ionic for my navigation.html page (a partial file located in the www/templates/ directory) but it's not working with partials files except with index.html root file only. However, it gives me error if I use it in the index.html root file, maybe because it needs to draw a svg in the navigation.html page, but it could not find the navigation.html page since it is in the index.html (dependency with the navigation.html)

I am thinking to use bower, but can bower solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In index file add the script tag to add scripts.

`<script src="./templates/PathFinding.js/"`>`

It will get loaded.

However, if you use Bower.. Bower will only download the files to `src` folder .. then you need to manually add script tags for script into the `index.html`.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question. I am sorry if my question is not very clear to you. I have mentioned that I cannot include those third party libraries in my index file as I will receive some error, maybe due to dependency (dependency on the navigation.html). So can bower solve this problem?

Comment: but, i don't think it may create any issue... Show the error you are getting or console logs if any.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. It is a long error. However it says the error comes from raphael.js. Raphael js is for us to draw svg. So I guess the index file cannot draw the svg as it does not have the depencies or the place to draw the svg.

Comment: Check the network panel if all the js files are getting loaded .. or some are 404. Handling dependencies without any extra effort is the best part of Angular.